# percona won't start after uncommenting innodb lines in my.cnf

Tags: centos, innodb, percona, my.cnf

I'm running `Percona 5.5` on a `Centos 6.3`. I'm using the prepackaged "huge" **my.cnf** which ships with percona, it matches my server specs pretty well. My database uses innodb tables. Reading the my.cnf file, there is a section pertaining to innodb:

```
# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 100M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

I uncommented the above lines (obviously leaving the actual comments commented), restarted percona and I get the following message:

```
Starting MySQL (Percona Server). ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/rmdb.pid).
```

I'm new to managing a database server. What benefit is there to uncommenting the above lines, and why does it crash `mySQL` when I restart when I do?

Thanks